# mocking an autowired object and calling a method from that object

Tags: junit, autowired

I have a class like this shown below:

```java
public class Service {
    @Value("${value1"})
    String val1;
    
    @Value("${value2"})
    String val2;
    
    @Value("${value1"})
    String val3;
    
    @Autowired
    Client obj;
    
    public String getResponse(String location, WebRequest request) {
        // getting invocation target exception
        String id = (String)request.getAttribute(Globals.id, request.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        Point p = obj.getPoint(new Id(val1, val2, val3), "some string");
    
        // do something
        return getReply(id);
    }
}
```

My test class is shown below:

```java
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    WebRequest request;
    
    @Mock
    Service service;
    
    @Mock
    Client obj;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetResponse() throws Exception {
        when(request.getAttribute(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyInt()).thenReturn("shbchdbchd");
        when(obj.getPoint(Id.valueOf("id"), "some string").thenReturn("shbchdbchd");
        service.getResponse("some location",request);
    }
```

But the `when(obj.getPoint)` is not working, the parameters are `null` in the actual call in the class `Service`. This line

```java
obj.getPoint(new Id(val1, val2, val3), "some string");
```

is getting `null` parameters.

Comment: I think you dont want to mock your Service service in the ServiceTest class?

Comment: how do i call my service then? could you paste your code here for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using Spring in your `Service` class and no Spring in your unit test. As you're at the moment mocking all member variables in the class `ServiceTest` the unit test doesn't really test anything from the `Service` class.
A solution would be to manually setup your `service` instance in the unit test.

```java
public class Service {
//....
    @Autowired
    public Service (
        @Value("${value1"}) String value1,
        @Value("${value2"}) String value2,
        @Value("${value3"}) String value3,
        Client client
    ){
        this.val1=value1;
        this.val2=value2;
        this.val3=value3;
        this.obj=client;
    }
//....
    public String getResponse(String location, WebRequest request) {
        // getting invocation target exception
        String id = (String)request.getAttribute(Globals.id, request.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        //should you pass id instead of val1,val2,val3?
        Point p = obj.getPoint(new Id(val1, val2, val3), "some string");
    
        // do something
        return getReply(id);
    }
}
```

```java
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    WebRequest request;
    
    @Mock
    Client obj;
    
    Service service;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        service = new Service("value1","value2","value3",obj);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetResponse() throws Exception {
        when(request.getAttribute(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyInt()).thenReturn("shbchdbchd");
        when(obj.getPoint(Id.valueOf("value1","value2","value3"), "some string").thenReturn("shbchdbchd");

        service.getResponse("some location",request);
    }
```

but to me it's still unclear what you really want to test.